# How to configure storybook story for module with RouterLink

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Cannot configure story for module where `routerLink` is used due to error

`ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicModule)[RouterLinkActive -> Router]`

To Reproduce
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
[demo-app](https://github.com/Adam-Michalski/theme-demo-app)
Run app and you can test that there is no possible solution to add RouterModule to work with story.
It cannot be configured with `RouterTestingModule`, `RouterModule`, `RouterModule.forRoot` with `iframe.html` path. There is always the same error about missing provider.

Expected behavior
To run application and story with routerLink

Additional context
Latest version of storybook `5.3.3` and angular `~8.2.14`
I was working with different configuration 5.2.8 and this issue does not appear.

**How to configure this module, is there an issue in storybook?**

[Storybook issue](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/9442)

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer to this question? Does the answer proposed by Ling Vu work for you?

Comment: Any feedback? Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you are working with angular 15 and also want to render the router-outlet, I was able to solve it like this:

in preview.js:

```
const globalModuleImports = moduleMetadata({
  imports: [RouterTestingModule, RouterModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [Router],
});


const setRoutesMetadata = (fn, c) => {
  const story = fn();
  story.moduleMetadata.providers.push(
    {
      provide: ENVIRONMENT_INITIALIZER, multi: true, useValue() {
        inject(Router).resetConfig(c.parameters?.routes || [])
      }
    }
  )
  return story;
}

export const decorators = [
  globalModuleImports,
  setRoutesMetadata
];
```

and then in your story you can set routes inside a story parameters:

```
  SomeStory.parameters = {
    routes: [
      {
        path: "second",
        loadChildren: () => import('./second/second-routes'),
      },
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

Storybook works different than angular so I dont need to inject `FeatureModule` into story, `Component` is just fine. When only `NavbarComponent` is injected with `RouterTestingModule`

story configuration looks like this

```
storiesOf('Navbar', module)
  .addDecorator(
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [NavbarComponent],
    }),
  )
```

And you don't need routes configuration xD

Comment: I still don't see the point in injecting `RouterTestingModule` which is supposed to be used in Unit tests and mock the routes, but it's okay if it works for you.

Comment: This provides mocks for needed directives, and as storybook works it is only for presentation so full RouterModule is not required

Answer (score 7):

I made the following changes:

1. Adding the `RouterModule` including the the routes array (used to define your routes)
2. Provide the required APP_BASE_HREF.

**navbar.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [NavbarComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'}],
  exports: [NavbarComponent]
})
export class NavbarModule {
}
```

After that you just need to add the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` into your `NavbarComponent`

Comment: This does not solve problem, there is the same problem

Answer (score 3):

With **Angular v15** and **Storybook v7**

The only way that worked for me for the `routerLink` to work and also render the `router-outlet` was by using `applicationConfig` for providing the router stuff like this:

```
const meta: Meta<RoutingTabsComponentExt> = {
    title: "UI Bricks/Web Only/Routing Tabs",
    tags: ["autodocs"],
    component: RoutingTabsComponent,
    decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
            imports: [RoutingTabsModule],
        }),
        applicationConfig({
            providers: [provideRouter(routes)],
        }),
        componentWrapperDecorator((story) => `${story}`),
    ],
};
```

I just prepared some dummy data for it and the storybook was able to route and render without issues

```
@Component({
    standalone: true,
    template: `
        <h1>First Tab</h1>
        <p>This is the content of the first tab</p>
    `,
})
class FirstStoryContentComponent {}

@Component({
    standalone: true,
    template: `
        <h1>Second Tab</h1>
        <p>This is the content of the second tab</p>
    `,
})
class SecondStoryContentComponent {}

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "tab1",
        loadComponent: () => FirstStoryContentComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "tab2",
        loadComponent: () => SecondStoryContentComponent,
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "tab1",
        pathMatch: "full",
    },
];
```

Hope that it helps someone, since it took me hours to figure out and none of the solutions that are out there were working for me :).